# Php, PDO, Sql, Try Catch ,Connection

Tags: php, sql, pdo

When i am using try catch block for example:

```
try{
     require_once('../php/connect.php');
     $dbh = db::getInstance();
     // What i am trying to understand should i close the connection here before the header?
     header("Location: x.php");
   }
} catch(PDOException $e){
   require_once('err.php');
 }
 $dbh = null; // Or should i close the connection here?
```

Is the "interpreter" even get after line "5", Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: That doesn't make sense at all. You are setting $dbh and if that doesn't throw an exception you will send a Location header, which will exit the script. I don't see your question.

Comment: You realise you have double } mistake also?

Comment: I am sorry if my code doe's not make any sense, it's becouse its just part of a code, between the connection to the header you can ask a question when you press send the the code below the connection enter your data into the database and the header taking you to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are not using `exit` after `header()` (which is [recommended](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)), your code will continue to execute.

As such, it does not matter if you put in on line 4 or 10. Furthermore, as pointed out by **prodigitalson**, you do no need to explicitly [close the database connection](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php).

Comment: If i got you right, The header will wait until the the script is finish then take the user to the x.php location, When you exit; after the header you are killing the rest of the script/connection, I did saw at the connection link, php manual using die() at the catch block, If you can tell me please, Doe's the catch block close the connection automatically?, Becouse if it doe's, I understand that the manual using die() so the code won't continue to be interpreted, Or if the catch won't close the connection die() will close the connection and stop the code to be interpreted.

Comment: You are right about using `exit` after `header()`. No, `catch` does not close the connection automatically. The connection is closed automatically when PHP exits - either normally or explicitly with `exit`, `die`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to close the connection at all. It will be closed when php exits. However, you arent calling `exit` after `header`...

Your code doesnt make sesne though, If the db connection is successful why would you redirect without doing anything???? If using header at all i would think you would call it to redirect to an error page (ie. in your `catch` block).